# IDXGISurface1 thread-safety/synchronization rules for GetDC/ReleaseDC?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, direct3d, dxgi

What are the thread-safety rules for `IDXGISurface1` `GetDC/ReleaseDC` for textures created with `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GDI_COMPATIBLE`?

Can I interact with `ID3D11Device` and `ID3D11DeviceContext` between `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC` on another thread, without data-races or blocking due to implicit synchronization? Or am I in order avoid the GPU idling forced to create a separate `D3D11Device` for the thread doing GDI rendering and then transferring it back to the "main"`D3D11Device` by copying to a `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_KEYED_MUTEX`?

i.e. is the following valid?

```
thread 1:

D3D11Device::CreateTexture2D // Create texture 1

IDXGISurface1::GetDC // Get DC for texture 1

... // Draw to texture1 using GDI

IDXGISurtface1::ReleaseDC // Release DC for texture1

thread 2:

// Is this valid if thread 1 is drawing using GDI?

D3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets

D3D11DeviceContext::Draw // Draw texture2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two bullet points from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to suggest that not only is this thread  unsafe, but there is a reduction in the device's capabilities while an HDC is outstanding.

- You must release the device(they are referring to the HDC) and call the IDXGISurface1::ReleaseDC method before you issue any new Direct3D commands.
- This method fails if an outstanding DC has already been created by this method.

Getting an HDC from the DXGISurface inherently involves the surface's parent D3D11 DC. Multi-threaded access of a D3D11 DC is also unsupported. From this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page: If multiple threads must access a single ID3D11DeviceContext, they must use some synchronization mechanism, such as critical sections, to synchronize access to that ID3D11DeviceContext.

I would attempt to prepare the GDI drawing on a seperate thread as you stated, but render it to a system memory buffer. Then simply blit the contents to the DXGI surface.

Also note most of these topics address the behavior of the immediate context, the [D3D11 Deferred Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may have different behavior.